# Maintaining two github user accounts

Tags: git, github

I use github from two different accounts , one is professional and one is personal. When git push some code to my repo that exist on personal account it is trying to push with a user name of professional account

**git push origin master** says:
`Permission to X/abc.git denied to Y
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/X/abc.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

However git remote -v says:
origin  https://github.com/X/abc.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/X/abc.git (push)

I have already checked
1- my ssh key exist in my personal account
2- O/p of ssh@github.com -v:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/akash.bansal/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/akash.bansal/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/akash.bansal/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/akash.bansal/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA     16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/akash.bansal/.ssh/known_hosts:77
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/akash.bansal/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.112]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi X! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

3- git config user.name
`X`
4- git config user.email
`X's email`
5- git config reads

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/X/abc.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

P.S. This repo directory is created on local then trying to link with remote directory. If i clone a remote directory, everything works fine.
Please tell me what i am missing?

Comment: You seem to be quite confused about the difference between git and github. You don't have an account on git; you have an account on github.

Comment: Although I'm sure you can get this to work, and I do it myself, github recommends the use of a **single** account for both personal and professional. Makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configurations `user.name` and `user.email` are only relevant when making commits. That’s what Git will write into the commit objects as the author and committer of your commits. It however does not affect any authentication with a remote repository; Git actually has no concept of authentication, that is only provided by the transport layer of the connection.

In your case, you are using SSH. SSH will use a public/private key combination to authenticate you. By default, SSH will use the key located at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, and that’s also what your log confirms:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/akash.bansal/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
```

So that key is being used to authenticate you. It probably belongs to your professional account, so GitHub will only see your professional account, not giving you access to your personal repository.

In order to change that, you would have to supply a different SSH key. This is a bit complicated to do, since both keys will target the same host (GitHub). You could set up an SSH configuration for this though. To do that, create `~/.ssh/config` and put the following inside (modify it to match your public key paths):

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal-profile_id_rsa
```

Once that’s done, you can use the remote URL `git@github-personal:X/abc.git` to access the repository `X/abc.git` with your *personal* key, and `git@github.com:X/abc.git` to access it with your *professional* key.

Alternatively, you could also switch to the HTTPS URLs, as those allow you to specify your username inside the URL:

```
https://professional@github.com/X/abc.git
https://personal@github.com/X/abc.git
```

Comment: Bingo! It works, i think that one needs to add private ssh key in private github account

Comment: Yes, of course you need to add the **public** keys for both your professional and personal account to the respective GitHub account.